# Terraform always start t3 instance in auto scaling group with unlimited credit setting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, autoscaling

I'm trying to create t3 instance inside autoscaling group by Terraform.
The launch template:

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "example" {
    ...
    credit_specification {
        cpu_credits = "standard"
    }
}
```

The autoscaling group

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "example" {
    ...
    mixed_instances_policy {
        launch_template {
            launch_template_specification {
                launch_template_id = aws_launch_template.example.id
                version            = "$Latest"
            }
        }

        override {
            instance_type     = "t3a.medium"
        }
    }
}
```

The t3a.medium's credit specification is always set as `unlimited`.

According to terraform [document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_template#credit-specification), I know this is the behavior of terraform.
But how can I override the credit specification of the instance?

Comment: You mean like adding an argument to override the credit specification?

Comment: @Marko E, yes, something like that. I tried to used override by launch template but It still no used at all. If the override by launch template can take effect, It will be enough.

Comment: How would that work if someone tries to specify a t2 instance? Not sure I completely understand the issue.

Comment: @Marko E, I just want to start a t3 instance with credit specification as standard, not unlimited as default.